# Почему у нас нет сообщества типа Super User?

Tags: предложение

Бывает, что проблема кроется не в программной, а в технической части, к примеру, что-то сломалось, я не знаю, звук пропал или еще что-то. А у нас нет русскоязычного сообщества по этой тематике, на SO такие вопросы задавать нельзя, как я понял. Стоит ли ждать SuperUser на русском? ruSU?

Comment: Потому что у компании пока нет планов мигрировать иные сообщества, коме SO, на другие языки.

Comment: Как мне кажется, это все–таки дубликат. Предыдущий вопрос (и ответ на него), на мой взгляд, полностью раскрывает проблему. Если это не так, пожалуйста, уточните ваш вопрос.

Comment: А вы попробуйте, раз вы считаете вашу идею толковой и полезной. Создайте предложение на [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) или хотя бы попытайтесь. Киньте ссылку сюда, расскажите кому можете о вашей идее (друзьям, коллегам и т.д.). Возможно, даже Николас вам поможет в популяризации этого сайта (хотя возможно и нет). В любом случае вас пошлют на Зону51, так как вряд ли есть другой способ создать сайт сети StackExchange.

Comment: Зато если у вас получится, вы сделаете крутейший прецент: неанглоязычное не-StackOverlow сообщество и откроете двери для создания других сообществ на русском.

Comment: @Vadim Ovchinnikov, вы чего издеваетесь? Серьезный вопрос, а вы шутите!

Comment: Посмотрел я эту зону 51 какая то военная база это что за шуточки?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov [сюрпри-и-и-и-из!](https://rus.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Ой простите, перешел я туда, но сразу ушел

Comment: Как-то отпало желание, что либо делать, в последнее время все становится невозможным. Ничего никогда не станет реалией.

Comment: @Flippy Ну не хотите — не делайте, раз вам это так сложно. Если бы мне эта идея очень интересовала, то я бы попробовал. Я просто в этих вещах не спец (тематика SuperUser), поэтому вряд ли смогу основательно за это взяться.

Answer (score 3):

Еле ruSO подняли; докажем что сообщество нужно (есть требования по посещениям, вопросам/ответам и т. п.) - сделают.

Comment: Грубо то как! Потому что. Фи!

Answer (score 2):

> Стоит ли ждать SuperUser на русском?

Не стоит (по крайней мере, пока у системных администраторов не будет своего сообщества с длинной историей на SO-подобном движке).

Джоэл Спольски ответил на вопрос «[Commitment phase for non-English proposals, is there any chance without English community support?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53659/357761)» *(«Фаза приёма заявок касательно неанглоязычных сообществ: есть ли шансы без поддержки существующего англоязычного сообщества?»)* [следующим образом](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53821/357761):

> Наша цель — создавать рабочие сайты.
>
> Для этого мы ввели крайне жёсткие ограничения и позволили существовать лишь тем немногим сайтам, которые имеют сильную поддержку. Со временем мы ослабим эти ограничения при условии, что создаваемые сайты будут работать. К примеру, если 90% всех сайтов, дошедших до стадии беты, просуществуют хотя бы три месяца, набирая при этом значительную базу полезных вопросов и ответов, мы упростим процесс принятия заявок.
>
> ---
>
> *Our goal is to make sites which work.*
>
> *At first, we will do this by having very strict criteria, and only creating a tiny number of sites for which there is overwhelming support. As time goes on, we will relax the criteria, as long as the sites that get created actually work. If, say, 95% of the sites that make it to beta actually survive for three months and get a lot of of good Q&A and help a lot of people, we'll make it easier and easier to get past the commitment phase.*

То есть огромное количество существующих англоязычных инициатив попросту не проходит дальше беты. Какие тут локализованные сообщества, со своими бы разобраться.

Однако, если по определённой теме накопится критическая масса пользователей (как это было с Хэшкодом), [есть все шансы пройти с заявкой до конца](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20988), пишет Тим Пост:

> Для рассмотрения локализованного сообщества, отличного от Stack Overflow, на целевом языке уже должен существовать сам локализованный SO. В придачу, нужно активное содействие со стороны существующего менеджера сообщества, знающего язык этого сообщества.
>
> ---
>
> *In order for us to consider a localized site other than Stack Overflow, Stack Overflow must currently exist in the target language. Additionally, we positively must have community manager cycles to spare, from someone fluent in the target language.*