# Прошу поддержать сообщество "Химия" на Area 51

Tags: поддержка

Прошу поддержать сообщество "Химия" на Area 51

Поискал сайт по типу, где можно химические вопросы по задавать (но увы, так и не смог такой найти). Сам интересуюсь биохимией.

[ВОТ  :3](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/123300/?referrer=MTZlYmMwNWMzOWI5NGYzNDJhZmFkYWI3YWY5MmNiYjRjM2QxZGRlMThjZTZlMWEwMjA2YWEzY2Y4ODYwYTdhZUlN993EPhFbY8rQ7Jaweil1neBewPAuqF-r15_Y0SRg0)

---

В общем, закрыли инициативу. Я вот посмотрел есть  http://math.hashcode.ru.

А можно ли на его базе (по его типу создать) http://chemistry.hashcode.ru? С кем об этом стоит поговорить?

Comment: Новых сообществ не на английском языке никогда больше не будет.

Comment: Связанные вопросы: [Почему у нас нет сообщества типа Super User](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5443/208074), [Как создать русскоязычный сайт на StackExchange](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1253/208074).

Comment: 228 в гости просим?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я сам попробовал, но потом сдался хотел свой сайт поднять увы не вышло :(

В принципе могу посоветовать сайт https://toxu.ru/  именно на нём я стал выкладывать свои вопросы по Биохимии.

:3

Answer (score 7):

1. [Новых сообществ не на английском больше никогда не будет](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20988/97647).
2. В создании хешкода принимал участие [Николай](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky). Можете у него узнать, что да как.
3. Никто вам не запрещает создать свой собственный сайт (: